# Put object always in front of other - web gl

Tags: web-applications, webgl

newbie question: how can i make a 3D object in web-gl, to always stand in front of an other 3D object.

Googling did not help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Without actually moving the object in front of the others, you would need to:

1. render a scene without that object to framebuffer
2. render scene only with that object to framebuffer
3. blend those two FBOs as a post-processing

Another way is to turn off the depth testing, with `gl.disable(gl.DEPTH_TEST)`, but I haven't done that so I don't know what problems you might encounter. The first option is stable and bullet-proof. :)

Hope this helps.

Comment: And how am I going to do this? A piece of code please? I have a loop where in every repeat I draw a cube and I want some cubes to be in front of others. thank you in advance.

Comment: You really only need this tutorial: http://learningwebgl.com/blog/?p=1786

Once you have two textures with rendered scenes, you draw a full-screen quad and apply those two textures, blending them in some way to suit your needs.